# Asp.net Button Click Event and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, event-handling

When clicking the button for first time change button text, on 2nd click redirects to other page -

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int clickCount;
    protected void btn_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1)
            (sender as Button).Text = "go to landing page";
        else
            Response.Redirect("LandingPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

As obvious every time page reloads clickCount will be re-initialized and else block is never going to execute.
To maintain the clickCount state I may use view state, session state, application state, hidden field or JS code may be etc. What is best for this particular case -> Ques 1.

As MVC is stateless and similar code written in controller as well, will re-initlialize clickCount every time ActionHandler or controller is instantiated. How do you handle similar situation in ASP.NET MVC -> Ques. 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model to pass into the view with the property on it:

```
public int ClickCount{get;set;}
```

Then in the view, create a hidden value

```
@Html.HiddenFor(f=>f.ClickCount)
```

During the post event on the controller, update the model

```
public ActionResult(ViewModel model){
model.ClickCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to keep track of button clicks, I would use google analytics.  If I wanted to keep track of them for within my own application, I would use a database (just make it update a database record on submit or click).  If I didn't/ couldn't use a database, you could create a hidden field and keep updating it with the number of button clicks, like so:

Controller:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function MyFormPost(Optional ByVal clicks As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
  ViewBag.Clicks += clicks
  Return View()
End Function
```

View:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
    @Html.Hidden("clicks", ViewBag.Clicks)
End Using
```

Note: This is VB.NET.

Comment: I am new to google analytics, how this can be integrated in this sample code, can u pls. enlighten me. +1

Comment: Put google analyics code (that you get when you create an analytics account on google.com) in your template (layout in /views/shared/_myTemplate.vbhtml or whatever you call it).  Google will automatically track all clicks and click-through paths.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

Depends:

- do you need to use this click count anywhere else on the application?
- is this count a sensible information?
- is there a problem if the user sees this counting?

IMO, the best solution would be to keep the count on the viewstate, but it may change according to the above questions.

**Question 2**

It would be **very** different. To start, you wouldn't have a "button clicked event", you would *get* (or *post*) an action from your controller. So, as you can see, it would require a total different approach.

Side note: remember that it's not only MVC that is stateless. HTTP is stateless by design.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution to this problem, but it should put you on the right track.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btn_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int clickCount;
        try
        {
            clickCount = int.Parse(Session["ClickCount"]);
            clickCount++;
        }
        catch
        {
            clickCount = 1; 
        }

        Session["ClickCount"] = clickCount;

        if (clickCount == 1)
        {
            (sender as Button).Text = "go to landing page";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("LandingPage.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

By using Session it will persist if the user leaves the page and comes back. (Only within a certain time frame. If you want it to persist longer, then use a cookie.)